# How do I use the change_form.html template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have my models and I would like to make use of the Django change_form template to edit my data.
Currently I have created my own template that works fine but lacks some of the basic stuff that change_form template might have, like fields validation.

Please give examples showing how should I call the template from my view, and what object variables need to be sent to the template.

Pointers to external projects/links that make use of this templates will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only change_form.html template I know of is in Django's admin application.  You don't use the template directly, you'll want to set up the admin application for editing your data.  In order to do that, follow the steps in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin).  If you have problems, post those problems as separate, specific questions.